# detect the difference between close and refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I know all the easy answers concerning onbeforeunload, click and keypress. but still, the browser seems to know what is happening, therefore, somewhere that information should be available.

try it, make such a page with onbeforeunload. you'll see that whenever you refresh, the popup mentions something about reloading. yet if you go to a completely different page, the confirmbox mentions something about navigation.

is there any guru who knows this and if this is (gonna be) possible?

Comment: Not sure what browser you are using but  messages in browsers will not be consistent browser to browser. Short answer is there is no way to tell users intent using javascript. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You could use the onbeforeunload to set a variable in a cookie. Then check the cookie the next time the page is loaded to see if it was loaded again within something like 5-10 seconds. That could be a refresh.

Comment: @JosephEvans yeah, but that is not the intention, the intention is to show that messagebox only when navigating away (this should be or made possible, with keeping the security of the browser confirmbox).  If I wanted to detect if the browser had refreshed the page i'd put a cookie on the table as bait...but no.

Comment: @charlietfl, browser is chrome, did not check firefox/ie yet.